# OpenCV and Python code Error Cap not defined...but is

Tags: python, opencv

Admittedly this is sort of Frankencode from my delving a little over my head in one part of a personal project.  Building a 'camera' out of a Raspberry Pi and the High Quality Camera kit and attempting to use the edge.py sample to do something akin to Focus Peaking with it.  When I push a button, the GPIO would trigger a window to open, and kill the window when released...  I found how to make it go full screen and cleared up most of the errors and then hit a wall.

That said, I'm getting the following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 244, in _call_when_changed
    super(RPiGPIOPin, self)._call_when_changed()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/local.py", line 143, in _call_when_changed
    self.state if state is None else state)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 293, in _call_when_changed
    method(ticks, state)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 197, in _pin_changed
    self._fire_events(ticks, bool(self._state_to_value(state)))
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 368, in _fire_events
    self._fire_activated()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 397, in _fire_activated
    super(HoldMixin, self)._fire_activated()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 344, in _fire_activated
    self.when_activated()
  File "CameraStart1.py", line 13, in FocusPeakingStart
    _flag, img = cap.read()
NameError: name 'cap' is not defined
```

This is the original code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
This sample demonstrates Canny edge detection.

Usage:
  edge.py [<video source>]

  Trackbars control edge thresholds.

'''

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# relative module
import video

# built-in module
import sys


def main():
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except:
        fn = 0

    def nothing(*arg):
        pass

    cv.namedWindow('edge')
    cv.createTrackbar('thrs1', 'edge', 2000, 5000, nothing)
    cv.createTrackbar('thrs2', 'edge', 4000, 5000, nothing)

    cap = video.create_capture(fn)
    while True:
        _flag, img = cap.read()
        gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thrs1 = cv.getTrackbarPos('thrs1', 'edge')
        thrs2 = cv.getTrackbarPos('thrs2', 'edge')
        edge = cv.Canny(gray, thrs1, thrs2, apertureSize=5)
        vis = img.copy()
        vis = np.uint8(vis/2.)
        vis[edge != 0] = (0, 255, 0)
        cv.imshow('edge', vis)
        ch = cv.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break

    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)
    main()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here's mine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from __future__ import print_function
from gpiozero import Button 
from signal import pause
from time import sleep
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import video
import sys

def main():
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except:
        fn = 0
    def nothing(*arg):
        pass
    cv.namedWindow('edge', cv.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    cap = video.create_capture(fn)

def FocusPeakingStart(): 
    while True:
        _flag, img = cap.read()
        gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        edge = cv.Canny(gray, 2000, 4000, apertureSize=5)
        vis = img.copy()
        vis = np.uint8(vis/2.)
        vis[edge != 0] = (0, 255, 0)
        cv.imshow('edge', vis)
        ch = cv.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break

def FocusPeakingStop(): 
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

buttonFocs = Button(14)

buttonFocs.when_pressed = FocusPeakingStart
buttonFocs.when_released = FocusPeakingStop

pause()
```

Appreciate any advice on where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Your version of `cap` is a local variable inside `main()`, not available anywhere else in the program.  And since you never actually called `main()`, it doesn't exist inside that function, either.

Comment: Thanks Jason, was seeing that this morning although I did try a few ways last night before finally posting.  Meh...kinda got something now with the window coming up.  Not totally sure how to kill it but I have a feeling that needs to be a new question.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jason, kinda hit me in the middle of the night it was something like that.  Have it halfway worked out now, but I think I created a new question.  I moved the cap variable into the focus peaking function.  The window now opens...although I'm having problems making the button release kill the new window.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I've got more reputation than I'll ever need.

Comment: Would help for the future, this isn't the first time :)